# Eclipse search only in shared files

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I often use 'File Search' in Eclipse CDT and use 'Enclosing project'. Results include matches within compilation folders that I am not interested about.

I can create a 'Working set' but I've got around 25 projects and changing the working set all the time doesn't make me work faster.

Is there a way to continue using 'Enclosing project' but filter out any file that is not coming form a repository / shared in the Team? I normally use SVN but I'd rather something that works for any file that has been shared in a repo.

Comment: Set the compilation folders as _derived_: right-click and choose _Properties: Resource_ and check the checkbox _Derived_. Derived files are by default excluded from the _File Search_ (there is a checkbox in the _File Search_ for that).

Comment: @howlger Great answer, solved my question. Would you like to put it as an answer so I can accept it please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Set the compilation folders as *derived***: **right-click** and choose ***Properties: Resource*** and check the checkbox ***Derived***.

Derived files are by default excluded from the *File Search* (in the *File Search* dialog is a checkbox that can be checked if derived files should also be searched).